# Accessing members of a tuple in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am having accessing contents of a tuple. Every time I run the code I get the error message index out of range. I am trying to use a for loop to go through the tuple.
I have tried everything and failed.

The code is below:

```
# Check friend(s) selection
myTuple = chat_FriList.get(0,END) 
tup = chat_FriList.curselection()
selected_friends = Listbox()        # to hold selected friends for group chat
selected_friends.delete(0, END)

for item in tup:
    user = myTuple[int(tup[item])]
    selected_friends.insert(END, user)

if (len(tup) !=0):
    print "Selected name:" + myTuple[int(tup[0])]
    count=0
    while count < len(friend_list):
        msg = friend_list[count]
        print selected_friends
        if dpkg(msg)[3] in selected_friends:           #dpkg(msg)[3] == myTuple[int(tup[0])]:
            connect_client(myID, myPort, dpkg(msg)[1], int(dpkg(msg)[2]), 'C', EntryText)
    count +=1
```

the full code is on this link. Basically im trying to create a group chat.
most of it working but i struggling to get a group chat going with selected users.  anyhelp will be appreciated.
see full code: 
[client.py](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B66BwJAE1pDhTmVQeHFlbUNxdW8&authuser=0)

[server.py](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B66BwJAE1pDhbDhqbzlDSzZVSEk&authuser=0)

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: Could you show the full error message and traceback?

Comment: You index into tuples with indices, not items. So, if your tuple is `('a', 'b', 'c')`, then `tup[0]` is 'a', and `tup['a']` is an error.

Answer (score 0):

More information is necessary to answer the question completely, but the following example from the REPL should be helpful.  More debugging on your behalf is probably the best strategy.

```
a = ("a", "b", "c")
for item in a
    print a[item]

a = (0, 1, 2)
for item in a
    print a[item]

a = (10, 11, 21)
for item in a
    print a[item]
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?   The IndexError could come from two places since you used a one liner.  Why don't you break down the one liner  further and see which tuple is being indexed incorrectly.

Comment: File "C:\Users\christos\Documents\PYTHON_FILES\client_guiVersion5_groupchat.py", line 224, in ClickAction
    user = myTuple[int(tup[item])]
IndexError: tuple index out of range